# Is there a way to guess the size of data.frame based on rows, columns and variable types?

Tags: r, memory, objectsize

I am expecting to generate a lot of data and then catch it R. How can I estimate the size of the data.frame (and thus memory needed) by the number of rows, number of columns and variable types?

Example.

If I have 10000 rows and 150 columns out of which 120 are numeric, 20 are strings and 10 are factor level, what is the size of the data frame I can expect? Will the results change depending on the data stored in the columns (as in `max(nchar(column))`)?

```
> m <- matrix(1,nrow=1e5,ncol=150)
> m <- as.data.frame(m)
> object.size(m)
120009920 bytes
> a=object.size(m)/(nrow(m)*ncol(m))
> a
8.00066133333333 bytes
> m[,1:150] <- sapply(m[,1:150],as.character)
> b=object.size(m)/(nrow(m)*ncol(m))
> b
4.00098133333333 bytes
> m[,1:150] <- sapply(m[,1:150],as.factor)
> c=object.size(m)/(nrow(m)*ncol(m))
> c
4.00098133333333 bytes
> m <- matrix("ajayajay",nrow=1e5,ncol=150)
> 
> m <- as.data.frame(m)
> object.size(m)
60047120 bytes
> d=object.size(m)/(nrow(m)*ncol(m))
> d
4.00314133333333 bytes
```

Comment: I did the following and got the following to get bytes per variable type

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can simulate an object and compute an estimation of the memory that is being used to store it as an R object using `object.size`:

```
m <- matrix(1,nrow=1e5,ncol=150)
m <- as.data.frame(m)
m[,1:20] <- sapply(m[,1:20],as.character)
m[,29:30] <- sapply(m[,29:30],as.factor)
object.size(m)
120017224 bytes
print(object.size(m),units="Gb")
0.1 Gb
```

Comment: I guess that the point is to know the size _before_  creating it.

Comment: @nicola it is an estimation. You can use as a reference assuming that the memory allocation is a linear function..

Comment: This solution works because after doing a few examples the user will be able to better estimate their output for other cases.

Comment: Yes, but what's the point of generating an object so similar to the one we want to create? One can just create the object and see. I guess that maybe one can see how much space a single column of a single type requires and do some math. This may work even for very large objects.

Comment: @nicola well but I think you simplify too much how memory is allocated, I don't know what do you mean by *some math* but I don't think you can get  the size memory using some additions.. take a look at `memory.profile()`

Comment: because of expected variances in size of object and also the practicalities of working in a server environment with many processes and users firing code, memory estimation is useful

Comment: In your example for instance, see how much close are `object.size(m)` and `object.size(m[[1]])*ncol(m)`. No reason to generate 150 columns.

Answer (score 3):

You could create dummy variables that store examples of the data you will be storing in the dataframe.

Then use `object.size()` to find their size and multiply with the rows and columns accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Check out `pryr` package as well.  It has `object_size` which may be slightly better for you.  From the [advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html)

> This function is better than the built-in object.size() because it accounts for shared elements within an object and includes the size of environments.

You also need to account for the size of `attributes` as well as the column types etc.

```
object.size(attributes(m))
```